# Задача с циклами

Tags: циклы, любой-язык

Как вывести на экран числа от 1 до 9, используя только два цикла for и необявляя в теле циклов переменнье.

Comment: Ваш вопрос решен?

Comment: если неважно на чем решать задачу то есть метка "любой язык"

Comment: `console.log(i*3+j+1)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Не очень внятное - "не объявляя в теле цикла переменные". Вне цикла можно? В заголовке можно?

Вот, на С++, вообще без переменных:

```
for(;;)
{
    for(;;)
    {
        cout << 1 << endl << 2 << endl << 3 << endl << 4 << endl << 5 << endl 
             << 6 << endl << 7 << endl << 8 << endl << 9 << endl;
        break;
    }
    break;
}
```

Формально верно, по существу - издевательство. Но мне что-то кажется, что имелось в виду что-то вроде

```
for(int i = 0; i < 3; ++i)
    for(int j = 1; j <= 3; ++j)
        cout << i*3 + j << endl;
```

Comment: Да, иммено ето имелось ввиду

Answer (score 1):

```php
for( ; ;) {

    for($i = 1; $i < 10; print $i . " ", $i++);
    break;

}
```

Comment: В условие указано - два цикла for

Comment: Для чего тут два цикла? Если задача вывести от 1 до 9.

Comment: Нет, в условие вказано - 2 цикла.

Comment: Правил ответ)))

Answer (score 0):

Напомнило задачку про 7 перпендикулярных линий, один в форме котика ([задача](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UoKlKx-3FcA), [решение](https://ic.pics.livejournal.com/service_picky/22497100/17613/17613_original.jpg))

Если усложнять, то по полной!)

```js
let i = +('~(=^_^=)').replace('~(=^_^=)', Math.ceil(Math.random()));

let j = +('(V)(;...;)(V)').replace('(V)(;...;)(V)', Math.floor(Math.random()));

for( i; i < Math.pow(3, 2) + Math.pow(0,0); i = i + Math.pow(0,0) ){
 for( j; j < Math.log10(10); j++ ){
  console.log( i );
 }
 j = Math.sin( 0 * Math.PI/180 );
}
```